# Dynamically add a control to page from a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How do I get my ASP.net webservice to add a control to my page if I call the webservise from inside the page load?

Below is a very simplified version of my code. Thanks

```
''''''''''''''''''page code behind'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            Dim m As New myWebService.Service

            m.DoThis()


        End Sub
    End Class



''''''''''''''''''''''Web service'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://test.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class Service
     Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function DoThis() As String


        Dim pg As Page = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)

        Dim txtb As HtmlButton = New HtmlButton()

        txtb.InnerText = "my bu-----tton"

        pg.Form.Controls.Add(txtb)

        Return "added"
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

The job of a webserivce is not to controls to a page.

Use your webservice to decide if some controls should be added to the Page, but the code to add the controls to the Page must be inside the Page.

If it is common code, you can add it to a common class or a helper function.

Think of a webservice as a methods you can call over the web, passing parameters and receiving processed values.

Adding controls to a Page does not really go well with the purpose of a web service.

Comment: thanks , so is there no way to do it?  what about passing the page context

Comment: A webservice is also a class. If your webservice is in the same project, there is nothing stopping your from adding functions to that class that will take the Page as a parameter and processing it. But you will not be able to serialize a Page and call the WebService over SOAP. Avoid writing code like this if possible. It would just confuse the next developer who has to maintain your code.

Comment: thanks-- any chance that you can point me in the right direction with the code I have above?

Comment: thanks I got it working by instantiating the class - that's what I wanted

Comment: but it wont let me pass httpcontext as a perameter. Do you have any ideas?