# pass the HttpContext.Current via json or instantiate object from a web service

Tags: c#, json

How do I pass the HttpContext.Current via json?

I'm guessing it is something like:

string hc = HttpContext.Current.toJSON

Here is my senario

I have 20  asp.net sites that I want to share a myAddControllsClass which uses the http context. This class adds controls to a page that it is instantiated on. I don't want to duplicate this class 20 times for maintainability issues. I also can't reference the DLL  `the only way I can do it is via a web service.`

```
//in page load

var my As New myAddControllsClassService.WebService

        my.addControlls(httpContext.Current)

//simplified version of my class
public class myAddControllsClass
{



    public void AddButton()
    {

            //scan controls in the context here

        Page pg = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

        HtmlButton txtb = new HtmlButton();

        txtb.InnerText = "my button";

        pg.Form.Controls.Add(txtb);

    }


}
```

Do you have any idea how to do this or any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Don't think you can pass the whole context. What exactly do you need to pass?

Comment: The context belongs to the place it was created. There is no reason to pass that to other place. It's like taking you apartment to your friend when you need to give him a furniture. Please describe your motivation to do so, maybe there is another way.

Comment: Passing "`HttpContext.Current` ... to a web service" doesn't really make sense.  What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: why can't you simply reference CodeLibrary dll ? Web Service can't create buttons for your sites, that methods have to execute in ASP.NET process. Even if you could do that new request for each control, that would be *very* slow

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot do that.

The same [explanation I gave you for a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036093/dynamically-add-a-control-to-page-from-a-web-service/12036183#12036183), applies here too.

> Think of a webservice as a methods you can call over the web, passing
>   parameters and receiving processed values.

`HttpContext.Current` is in context to your current request. It cannot be passed over web services. All objects cannot be serialized.

To pass data to a web service, you have to be able to serialize the data. Socket connections, file handles, etc cannot be serialized and rebuilt in the web service.

The ideal method to share code like this, would be to create a dll and reference it in all your projects that must share code. Why can you not do that?

Comment: +1 for the sentence "The ideal method to share code like this, would be to create a dll and reference it in all your projects that must share code."